# Additional text for ctrl+c keypress

Tags: .net, wpf, messagebox

As most MessageBoxes, the WPF MessageBox copies all of its contents (caption, text, buttons) to the clipboard if the user presses CTRL+C while the MessageBox is shown. So far everything is fine.

Now I would like to supply additional information, but only to the clipboard, not in the MessageBox itself. Does anyone know how I would do this?

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(this, "The Message", "MsgBox Caption", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
```

Comment: If you can't get a satisfactory answer, you might be able to build your own message box dialog that does what you want.  I don't think it would be difficult, because the message box class has a deliberately spartan design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sure! Just add whatever text you want to be copied to the message box!**

There's no good reason for wanting to do this any other way. And even if there were, it's not possible. This is not something implemented in WPF; the Win32 [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505.aspx) API does it internally. There's no button or switch to configure how it works.

Others have suggested creating your own message box form and trying to simulate this behavior, but I would very much advise against that. It's very difficult to get right all of the little things that the `MessageBox` API is actually doing for you behind the scenes.

The better solution is to upgrade to the [`TaskDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760540.aspx) API and add a "More Info" button to the dialog that drops down a panel displaying additional information about the message. Users are already familiar with this style of dialog, as it's used internally throughout current versions of the operating system. The less you deviate from your platform's conventions, the happier your users will be.

Comment: I'm using the TaskDialog API (WindowsAPI Code Pack) now. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

from : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188920.aspx

> Replacing the Static Text The message of the dialog box is rendered
>   through a window of the static class. The .NET Framework counterpart
>   of a Win32 static window is the Label class. The text displayed
>   through a static control window is not selectable with the mouse. To
>   partially remedy this behavior, with Windows 2000, Microsoft
>   introduced a little-known feature to simplify the task of copying the
>   text displayed in a standard message box to the clipboard. Try
>   pressing Ctrl+C when a message box window is displayed. Next, flush
>   the clipboard's contents to a textbox control with Ctrl-V. For the
>   sample window shown in Figure 1, you get the following text:
>
> —————————————
>
> Cutting Edge
>
> —————————————
>
> Hello, managed world!
>
> —————————————
>
> OK
>
> —————————————
>
> The text contains the message along with the window caption and the
>   button text. The feature depends on the operating system and cannot be
>   controlled programmatically. If you want to visually select the text
>   to copy to the clipboard, there is no way other than by replacing the
>   static control with a borderless read-only edit control.

So basicly you have to create your own messagebox control to control how text is sent to the clipbord.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you can not change contents in the clipboard, but you could just change the contents before it is copied, by triggering the key combination.

EDIT:

See below an example:

```
// Ctrl + C 
if ((Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) && (e.Key == Key.C)) { 
ProcessSaveCommand(); 
}
```

You have to bind a keydown event to your element and may process the data like shown above.

```
<TextBox KeyDown="KeyDownEventHandler" />

private void KeyDownEventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
// Ctrl + C 
if ((Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) && (e.Key == Key.C)) { 
ProcessSaveCommand(); 
} 
}
```

Comment: No, you certainly cannot do this.

Comment: That works for custom controls, but there is no way to inherit or override the MessageBox control to use this code.

Comment: The MessageBox is not an "element". This answer is still quite wrong. Make sure that you read the question before answering.